# mysql output split tested webpage count, conversions, percent

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that records hits to various landing pages, and then adds a conversion to each if there's a conversion. I would like to output a little table showing the total hits to each landing page, the conversions, and conversion % for each page with if possible a date selector, like "date >= Aug 18"

Database looks like so:

```
page |visitor ip | conversion | date
pg1  |  x.x.x    |    1       | Aug 19 
pg3  |  x.x.x    |    0       | Aug 19 
pg1  |  x.x.x    |    0       | Aug 19 
pg5  |  x.x.x    |    0       | Aug 19 
pg1  |  x.x.x    |    0       | Aug 19 
pg5  |  x.x.x    |    1       | Aug 19 
pg1  |  x.x.x    |    1       | Aug 19 
pg3  |  x.x.x    |    0       | Aug 19 
pg5  |  x.x.x    |    0       | Aug 19
```

Would like to output a table like so:

```
page  |  total hits  |   total conversions | conversion rate
pg1   |   4          |     2               |      50%
pg3   |   2          |     0               |       0
pg5   |   3          |     1               |       33%
```

thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `SUM`, `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`

Comment: Currently I have:

 SELECT page , count(page ) 
  FROM stats 
 GROUP by page 
 ORDER BY COUNT( page ) DESC 

but this just shows the first 2 columns, don't know how to add the total conversions to it

Comment: It's been a while and you did not select any answer, nor gave any feedback. It takes a lot to understand your problem, find a solution and write it up for you. If a solution worked for you, select and upvote it. If not, at least let us know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
 SELECT 
    page , 
    count(page) as 'total hits', 
    SUM(IF(conversion=1,1,0)) as 'total conversions',
    CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(IF(conversion=1,1,NULL))/count(page) * 100),'%') as Rate    

 FROM stats GROUP by page ORDER BY COUNT( page ) DESC
```

To get this result:

[image]

[**Live Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c4097/19)